# AngularJS ng-repeat over json query

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im using AngularJS in a project. In my view I repeat over some employees and show them on the screen. That works, but I have to use the code

```
<li ng-repeat="employee in employees.employee">
```

instead of

```
<li ng-repeat="employee in employees">
```

Why cant I directly access the employees to loop over the different json objects?

My code snippets of the project:

Controller

```
Test.controller('EmployeeListController', function($scope, Employee) {
    $scope.employees = Employee.query();
});
```

HTML View

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="employee in employees.employee">
        <a href="mailto:{{employee.email}}" title="{{employee.email}}">{{employee.firstName}} {{employee.lastName}} ({{employee.email}})</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Factory

```
Test.factory('Employee', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/TestServer/rest/employees/:employeeId', {}, {
        update: {method:'PUT'},
        query: {method:'GET', isArray:false}
    });
});
```

JSON Response

```
{"employee":[{"created":null,"description":"TestDescription","email":"TestMail","firstName":"TestFirstName","id":"1","image":"TestImage.jpg","lastModification":null,"lastName":"TestLastName","phone":"121212121212"},{"created":null,"description":"TestDescription","email":"TestEmail","firstName":"TestFirstName","id":"2","image":"TestImage2.jpg","lastModification":null,"lastName":"TestLastName","phone":"2124343434"}]}
```

Comment: Does your actual server response returns array? It's possible that your backend API is wrapping your collection inside the "root node", which in this case would be"employee".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeater is repeating over arrays. and in your response you are giving it an object. The array is actually on the employee attribute (in your json response and also because of the isArray: false)

Comment: I can see that the array is on the employee attribute. But Im wondering why it comes back like that. I also tried to change the isArray to true, but that did not change anything.

Comment: @Andy it depends on your server implementation